# PHP sort seems to malfunction

Tags: php, sorting

```
### Result of sort 

sort($keys_arranged, SORT_NUMERIC);
var_dump($keys_arranged);

{ ...
[51]=> float(11.903327742296) 
[52]=> int(5) 
[53]=> float(13.165002546636) 
[54]=> float(14.478273306964) 
[55]=> float(4.6264742674547) 
[56]=> float(13.290508819344) 
[57]=> float(15.686809055276) } 

### Result or rsort

rsort($keys_arranged, SORT_NUMERIC);
var_dump($keys_arranged);

{
[0]=> float(15.686809055276) 
[1]=> float(14.478273306964) 
[2]=> float(13.290508819344)
[3]=> float(13.165002546636) 
[4]=> float(11.903327742296) 
[5]=> int(5) 
[6]=> float(4.6264742674547)
... }

echo var_export($keys_arranged);

array ( 0 => 3.142678516658294, 1 => 1.0, 2 => 1.0, 3 => 14.478273306963985, 4 => 13.165002546635966, 5 => 1.0, 6 => 1.0005037081114851, 7 => 1.0, 8 => 4.6264742674547001, 9 => 15.686809055275578, 10 => 1.0, 11 => 11.903327742295504, 12 => 13.29050881934397, 13 => 1.0, 14 => 1.0, 15 => 3.5421134937189365, 16 => 1.0, 17 => 0.010999999999999999, 18 => 3.2999566681750605, 19 => 5, 20 => 1.2282984802843129, 21 => 1.0, 22 => 2.9748253120971184, 23 => 0.44855992975075798, 24 => 0.99999999999999989, 25 => 3.8350475954623371, 26 => 1.0625975061426283, 27 => 1.0000072792091179, 28 => 0.99999987785487132, 29 => 1, 30 => 0.0, 31 => 1.0, 32 => 1.0, 33 => 1.0, 34 => 0.0, 35 => 1.0972568578553616, 36 => 1.0, 37 => 1.4077661823957415, 38 => 1.0, 39 => 0.0, 40 => 3.6038030347555705, 41 => 1.0, 42 => 1.0, 43 => 1.0636876768842174, 44 => 1.0, 45 => NAN, 46 => 1.0, 47 => NAN, 48 => NAN, 49 => NAN, 50 => NAN, 51 => 1.0, 52 => 1.0, 53 => NAN, 54 => 0.99958680716631509, 55 => 1.0, 56 => NAN, 57 => 1.0, )
```

I got some incorrect result from array_multisort. It has 8 different keys and all the keys but this key(say A) works fine.

To figure out why that happened, I played with A in the array. And I could see that not only in the function of array_multisort, but also in 'sort' function, an incorrect result prompted as well.

As you can see the result of rsort seems okay, the result of sort works strangely when it comes to
13.16 < 14.47 < 4.62 < 13.29 < 15.68

Does anyone know why this occurred?

```
// Data in readible format

array (
0 => 3.142678516658294, 
1 => 1.0, 
2 => 1.0, 
3 => 14.478273306963985, 
4 => 13.165002546635966, 
5 => 1.0, 
6 => 1.0005037081114851, 
7 => 1.0, 
8 => 4.6264742674547001, 
9 => 15.686809055275578, 
10 => 1.0, 
11 => 11.903327742295504, 
12 => 13.29050881934397, 
13 => 1.0, 
14 => 1.0, 
15 => 3.5421134937189365, 
16 => 1.0, 
17 => 0.010999999999999999, 
18 => 3.2999566681750605, 
19 => 5, 
20 => 1.2282984802843129, 
21 => 1.0, 
22 => 2.9748253120971184, 
23 => 0.44855992975075798, 
24 => 0.99999999999999989, 
25 => 3.8350475954623371, 
26 => 1.0625975061426283, 
27 => 1.0000072792091179, 
28 => 0.99999987785487132, 
29 => 1, 
30 => 0.0, 
31 => 1.0, 
32 => 1.0, 
33 => 1.0, 
34 => 0.0, 
35 => 1.0972568578553616, 
36 => 1.0, 
37 => 1.4077661823957415, 
38 => 1.0, 
39 => 0.0, 
40 => 3.6038030347555705, 
41 => 1.0, 
42 => 1.0, 
43 => 1.0636876768842174, 
44 => 1.0, 
45 => NAN, 
46 => 1.0, 
47 => NAN, 
48 => NAN, 
49 => NAN, 
50 => NAN, 
51 => 1.0, 
52 => 1.0, 
53 => NAN, 
54 => 0.99958680716631509, 
55 => 1.0, 
56 => NAN, 
57 => 1.0, )
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190132/discussion-on-question-by-user3497957-php-sort-seems-to-malfunction).

Comment: Illustrative 3v4l: https://3v4l.org/JNPZE

Answer (score 2):

It seems as you actually do have discovered a bug. On large arrays containing `NaN` values, represented by the `NAN` constant in PHP, the built-in function `sort` fails.

The comparision with `NaN` should always result as non-ordered as mentioned by *kuh-chan* in the question comments. However, as soon as there is at least one operand `NaN`, in recent (March 2019) versions of PHP the spaceship operator `<=>` returns `1` *(first operand greater than second one)* and `-1` *(first operand less than second one)* in some other versions.

```
echo var_dump( NAN   <=> 1.23  );
echo var_dump( 1.23  <=> NAN   );
echo var_dump( NAN   <=> -1.23 );
echo var_dump( -1.23 <=> NAN   );
echo var_dump( NAN   <=> 0     );
echo var_dump( NAN   <=> NAN   );
```

I'm not very famimilar with the internals of the Zend engine. However, I guess the `sort` algorithm terminates too soon on large arrays with several `NaN` values, likely in order to the order comparision algorithm alway returns "greater (or less) than" which probably leads to multiple exchanges of the same elements.

I experienced that calling `sort` multiple times seems to continue the sorting. However, that would not be a proper workaround.

You can use a custom comparision algorithm with `usort` instead. If you want to order `NaN` at the start of the array, return `-1` when the first operand is `NaN`, `1` when the second operand is `NaN` and `0` *(equal)* if both are. Otherwise return the comparision result of the spaceship operator.

```
usort($keys_arranged,
  function(&$v1, &$v2)
  {
    switch( (is_nan($v1) ? 1 : 0) | (is_nan($v2) ? 2 : 0) )
    {
      case 0: return $v1 <=> $v2;
      case 1: return -1;
      case 2: return 1;
      case 3: return 0;
    }
  }
);
```

Similar bitwise logic as above, but in a more compressive and direct form:

```
usort( $keys_arranged,
       function(&$v1, &$v2){ return -2 === ($b = (is_nan($v1) ? -1 : -2) ^ (is_nan($v2) ? -1 : 0)) ? $v1 <=> $v2 : $b; }
     );
```

Comment: There are some complex sentences in my answer. It would be nice if a native speaker could improve my wording/grammar.

Comment: Your english is fine. :P